# tkinter - Can a radio button control multiple variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a calendar program using the tkinter module and clicking on each day on the grid will print out the current day's date (month/day/year). However, I also want to add another section at the bottom that will show what day of the year it is. Like this:

[image: [screenshot of desired output]

For example, January 1, 2020 would be the first day of the year, March 20 will be the 80th day of the year, etc. I want my radio buttons to be able to control both of these variables, the date as a string, and the day of the year as an integer. Is this possible?

```
strDate = StringVar()
labelDate = Label(frameDay, textvariable=strDate, width=28, 
                  font=("Consolas", "15", "bold")).grid(row=1, column=1)

# Creating the calendar grid
while day <= self.returnMaxDay():
    currentDay = Date(self.month, day, self.year)
    radDay = Radiobutton(frameCalendar, text=str(day), 
                         font=("Consolas", "15", "bold"), indicatoron=0, width=4, height=1, 
                         variable=strDate, value=str(currentDay.returnDayName()) + ", " 
                                                 + str(currentDay.returnMonthName()) + " "
                                                 + str(day) + ", " + str(currentDay.year))
    radDay.grid(row=row, column=weekDay)
    day += 1
    weekDay += 1

    if weekDay == 7:
        row += 1
        weekDay = 0

labelDayOfYear = Label(window, text=str(self.dayOfYear()), font=("Consolas", "20")).pack()
```

Comment: Associate a callback via `command` option and set the required variables to what you want in the callback.

Comment: @acw1668 Since I created my radio buttons with a while loop, the variable only takes the very last iteration of the while loop which will always be either 28, 29, 30, or 31. I'm not sure `command` will work.

Comment: brien: It will work, you're just not doing it right (but I can't tell you how to fix it without seeing your code). Also, in a couple of places you're assigning the result of calling `grid()` or `pack()` — which is always `None` — to a variable.

Comment: ***March 20 will be the 80th day of the year***: How do you calculate this? As `variable=` follows `value=` you can't, but you can build a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) object from the `value` string.

Comment: `radDay = Radiobutton(frameCalendar, text=str(day), font=("Consolas", "15", "bold"), indicatoron=0, width=4, height=1,\
                variable=strDate, value=str(currentDay.returnDayName()) + ", " + str(currentDay.returnMonthName()) + " "\
                    + str(day) + ", " + str(currentDay.year), command=intTotalDays.set(currentDay.dayOfYear()))` I'm not sure if I did it right. I added the command option at the end. `labelDayOfYear = Label(window, text=str(intTotalDays.get()), font=("Consolas", "20"))
        labelDayOfYear.pack()` This code prints out the day of the year.

Comment: if you `command=lambda:...` in loop then you may have to use `lambda arg=x:...`  to correctly assing value `command=lambda arg=x:function(arg)` instead of `command=lambda:function(x)

Comment: BTW: `command=` expects function's name without `()` and without arguments - ie. `command=intTotalDays.set` - and later Python uses `()` to run this function when you select widget - but it will not use arguments in this function. If you have to assign function with arguments then you may use `lambda` to create function without argument - `command=lambda:intTotalDays.set(currentDay.dayOfYear())`

Comment: @furas Thanks for being very specific. I think I got it to work now.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple example which uses `command=` in `Radiobutton` to run function which changes text it three `Labels`.

Normally `command=` expect function's name without `()` and arguments so I use `lambda` to assing function with arguments.

```
command=lambda d=current_day:on_click(d))
```

I also use `d=current_day` to create new variable `d` for every function. Without `d=current_day` all functions would use reference to the same variable `current_day` and all functions would use the same (last) value in `current_day`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

# --- functions ---

def on_click(value):
    print(value)
    label_date['text'] = value.strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y')
    label_day['text'] = value.strftime('Day: %d')
    label_weekday['text'] = value.strftime('Weekday: %a')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

radiobutton_var = tk.StringVar()

year = 2020
month = 4

row = 0

for day in range(1, 32):
    try:
        current_day = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)

        date_str = current_day.strftime('%a, %m %d, %Y')
        weekday = current_day.weekday()

        radiobutton_day = tk.Radiobutton(root,
                                text=str(day), 
                                indicatoron=0,
                                variable=radiobutton_var,
                                value=date_str,
                                #value=day,
                                command=lambda x=current_day:on_click(x))

        radiobutton_day.grid(row=row, column=weekday, sticky='we')

        if weekday == 6:
            row += 1
            radiobutton_day['bg'] = '#faa'

    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex) 
        break

label_date = tk.Label(root, text='?')
label_date.grid(row=10, columnspan=10)

label_day = tk.Label(root, text='Day: ?')
label_day.grid(row=11, columnspan=10)

label_weekday = tk.Label(root, text='Weekday: ?')
label_weekday.grid(row=12, columnspan=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

**BTW:** I use `datetime` to generate dates and `try/except` to catch error when date is incorrect.

I also use `strftime` to format date - see more on page [strftime.org](https://strftime.org/)